# Efficiently sorting a list of Work Order records by a Sequence

Tags: apex, map, sort, comparable

I have `Work_Order_Sequence__c` and `UniqueKey__c` field on Work Order object. In my method I wish to create a Map which has a `Key => UniqueKey__c` and `Value=> List<WorkOrder> (sorted)`. Basically grouping all the sorted work orders by  `UniqueKey__c`. Unfortunately I do not have option to do `ORDER BY` as these WO are `not in database.`

```
Example:
--------
#.          Work_Order_Sequence__c         UniqueKey__c

WO1                 3                          abc
WO2                 1                          abc
WO3                 2                          abc
WO4                 1                          xyz
WO5                 3                          xyz
WO6                 2                          xyz
```

The method I am creating takes the `unsorted List<WorkOrder>` as parameter.

I tried the below approach to sort the WorkOrders and group them by `UniqueKey__c`. However I see there are `two for loops` involved here. `Is there a more efficient way or more simplified way of achieving this?`

```
What I tried:

public with sharing class SortClass {
    public Map<String, List<WorkOrder>> groupWorkOrders(List<WorkOrder> woList) {
        Map<String, List<WorkOrderWrapper>> mapOfWrapByUnqKey = new Map<String, List<WorkOrderWrapper>>();
        Map<String, List<WorkOrder>> mapOfWOByUnqKey = new Map<String, List<WorkOrder>>();
        for (WorkOrder w : woList) {
            if (mapOfWOByUnqKey.containskey(w.uniqueKey__c)) {
                mapOfWOByUnqKey.get(w.uniqueKey__c).add(w);
                mapOfWrapByUnqKey.get(w.uniqueKey__c).add(new WorkOrderWrapper(w));
            } else {
                mapOfWOByUnqKey.put(w.uniqueKey__c, new List<WorkOrder>{ w });
                mapOfWrapByUnqKey.put(w.uniqueKey__c, new List<WorkOrderWrapper>{ new WorkOrderWrapper(w) });
            }
        }

        for (String s : mapOfWrapByUnqKey.keyset()) {
            mapOfWrapByUnqKey.get(s).sort();
            List<WorkOrder> wolst = new List<WorkOrder>();
            for (WorkOrderWrapper wr : mapOfWrapByUnqKey.get(s)) {
                wolst.add(wr.wo);
            }
            mapOfWOByUnqKey.put(s, wolst);
        }

        return mapOfWOByUnqKey;
    }

    public class WorkOrderWrapper implements Comparable {
        public WorkOrder wo;

        // Constructor
        public WorkOrderWrapper(WorkOrder w) {
            wo = w;
        }

        // Compare workOrders based on the WorkOrder seq.
        public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
            // Cast argument to WorkOrderWrapper
            WorkOrderWrapper compareTowo = (WorkOrderWrapper) compareTo;

            // The return value of 0 indicates that both elements are equal.
            Integer returnValue = 0;
            if (wo.Work_Order_Sequence__c > compareTowo.wo.Work_Order_Sequence__c) {
                // Set return value to a positive value.
                returnValue = 1;
            } else if (wo.Work_Order_Sequence__c < compareTowo.wo.Work_Order_Sequence__c) {
                // Set return value to a negative value.
                returnValue = -1;
            }

            return returnValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you querying the objects from the database? If so, could you not use an ORDER BY clause to ensure they are pre-sorted?

Comment: that's a good idea however in this case those WOs are not in database yet and is being passed to the above method.

Comment: Fair enough. Worth updating the question to clarify that point...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Consider mapping all your WorkOrders/Wrappers by a combination key  (i.e UniqueKey__c  + '.'+ Work_Order_Sequence__c.leftPad(10, '0') ).
2. sort your combo key
   list  comboKey = new List(mapWO.keyset()); combokey.sort();
3. iterate through sorted combokey and create a new list of WorkOrders/Wrappers.

   ```
    LIST<WO> wo = new LIST<WO>();
    for (string k : comboKey )
    wo.add(mapWO.get(k));
   ```

should not need the to implement comparable since you are converting to padded number and can just leverage the standard alpha sort.

Comment: great idea. However what if I say the uniqueKey is like 005q00000069k2d12/31/2020000002, basically uniqueKey is => a sfdc id + date +  Work_Order_Sequence__c.leftPad(10, '0'). Would this approach still work?

Comment: @SfdcBat sure just be sure it's truly unique and keep in mind that it will alpha sort unless you write your own sort alg by implementing Comparable

Comment: Yes the key will be unique for sure - 0Hnq00000000DtYCAU2020-06-02 00:00:00 1 . I see there is no need to use leftPad(10, '0') if the key is like sfdc id(0Hnq00000000DtYCAU) + date(2020-06-02 00:00:00)+ Work_Order_Sequence__c(1). What do you think?

Comment: leftPad({maxdigits}, '0') padding is used to sort the Work_Order_Sequence__c properly if you have values >=10   (i.e.  values 1, 2, 10, 11, 101  would sort as 1, 10, 101, 11,  2 without padding zeros.

Answer (score 4):

As I've [said](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/282831/2984) ... [at](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/204167/2984) ... [least](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/250056/2984) ... [four](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/199317/2984) times, just because you have a for loop inside another for loop, does not automatically make this a Bad Thing. Feel free to read the answers for more information. There are some minor optimizations that could improve performance, such as [not calling the `Map.get` method more than once per loop](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/179685/2984), sorting *before* putting them in the map (this would mean only one sort() call), and pre-initializing the map keys to remove the IF statements, but these hardly make a difference unless you're dealing with lists of thousands and need that extra kick.

Basically, your code is fine, don't worry about it.

Comment: thanks I do agree with your thought. Actually, I am dealing with thousands of records in the project and my idea is to reduce as much for loop as possible(if really possible). The above code is just part of a much more functionality. It just adds up.

Comment: @SfdcBat the fifth link actually includes a useful trick that's better for performance (at the cost of some legibility) you might like.

Comment: Nice idea. COuld you let me know about your idea on - "sorting before putting them in the map (this would mean only one sort() call ". Can you show me how?

Comment: @SfdcBat Gauge Boson beat me to it, actually. Just sort the records before putting them into the maps; they'll still be sorted when you're done. That said, the performance difference is probably close to zero because sorting is a linear-growth algorithm (in other words, it takes about 100 times longer to sort 100 items than to sort 1 item). The only change is that calling apex methods have some CPU cost, so calling the method once instead of 100 times saves 99 method calls and the corresponding overhead.